# How do I make slashes act as word separators in HOCR output (Tesseract OCR)?

Tags: tesseract, hocr

Is there any way to tell Tesseract OCR to treat certain characters as word separators in the HOCR output?

For example, say I have a document about the Scranton/Wilkes-Barre RailRiders, and I want the slash to be treated as a word separator.  So instead of this output:

```
<span class='ocrx_word' id='word_1_2' title='bbox 186 324 1201 395; x_wconf 85' lang='eng' dir='ltr'>Scranton/Wilkes-Barre</span>
```

I need output that looks like this (bboxes are estimated):

```
<span class='ocrx_word' id='word_1_2' title='bbox 186 324 799 395; x_wconf 85' lang='eng' dir='ltr'>Scranton</span>
<span class='ocrx_word' id='word_1_3' title='bbox 800 324 820 395; x_wconf 85' lang='eng' dir='ltr'>/</span>
<span class='ocrx_word' id='word_1_4' title='bbox 821 324 1201 395; x_wconf 85' lang='eng' dir='ltr'>Wilkes-Barre</span>
```

I have tried two possible solutions:

1. Setting "tessedit_char_blacklist" to "/".  This did not work as Tesseract simply changed the slash to a lowercase L.
2. Setting "chs_trailing_punct1" to ").,;:?!/" (the default characters plus the slash).  This did not change the output at all.

Comment: Have you tried setting `page_separator`

Comment: I'd suggest extracting the text as it is and swapping the characters you dont like for an empty space in the correctly OCRed string.

Comment: @GradaGukovic Thank you for the suggestion.  But I don't really need the words from the HOCR output. I need the bounding boxes, because the project is for automatically redacting certain words (especially personally-identifying information).  If two words are separated by a slash, we may need redact one of the words and not the other.

Comment: Do you mean want to  split the bbox wherever you have a slash?

Comment: @GradaGukovic Yes, that's what I need: a bounding box for the word before the slash and another bounding box for the word after the slash.

Comment: That is complicated,  as tesseract doesnt tell you the position of the words inside the bbox. If you know the relative size of different characterrs in the font thats used in the picture, the quality of the piture is good and you think it worth the effort you may attempt to compute, where the slash is. I murkily remember that we did something similar with my previous employer but if you're not into typesetting, its not going to be fun.